# Why exactly is this error occurring when the loop executes to completion and how do I stop it?

Tags: python, debugging

Code: http://pastie.org/1966795

Trackback: http://pastie.org/1966799

TXT File I'm using: http://pastie.org/1966800

Keep in mind the program runs, my only issue is that it displays an error message at the end (see: trackback), that I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens when `print_et_list` is executing for the *fourth* time. By then you're past the end of your input file, so [`readline`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) keeps returning empty strings. You should return from `print_et_list` early if `question` is blank, and correctly handle this case in `main`.

Comment: How do you propose I could handle this better? As is I set question to != "". And then I tried 'while question' as well. Both invoked the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the piece of code that fixed it. I caught the error within the main function. It seems a bit choppy to me, but it runs. If anyone of you see this and have a more elegant solution, I'm all ears.

http://pastie.org/1969148

I use slang in my code to pique interest haha sorry if it offends. It's not NSFW, no worries.

Comment: I'm relatively new to SO, but I have not seen a person's code listed on an external site before.  I suspect doing so affects searching in addition to making it harder for people to actually see the code.